# service contract save method flow - magento 2

Tags: magento2, database, service-contract, crud, magento2.0.8

I can able to get custom table records from database using **service contract** but hard to understand the **save** flow.

**di.xml**

```
<preference for="Mobi\Service\Api\RcRepositoryInterface" type="Mobi\Service\Model\RcRepository"/>
<preference for="Mobi\Service\Api\Data\RcInterface" type="Mobi\Service\Model\Rc"/>
```

can anyone explain the flow with some key codes?

Comment: @RaphaelatDigitalPianism that is the top link in google! it helps! however It bit hard to me understand the flow, only code snippet without much details. That's why I want make it as a smaller piece with some  additional explanation. :-)